# IUPAC nomenclature for an interesting looking organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

How can I name this organic compound while adhering to the IUPAC standards?

[image: A name could not be generated for this structure.]

Comment: Congratulations!  This structure breaks my favorite structure editor (ChemDoodle) when I attempt to have it name this molecule...

Comment: Not many online editors worked... unfortunately. :/

Comment: Hah! This is an awesome test case for chemical editors and layout engines. Layout seems particularly tricky for what should be a quite easy job.

Comment: Also, it looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexabenzocoronene minus some of the internal bonds.

Comment: Yea. Removing some of the internal bonds and adding two other phenyl groups gives you this compound.

Comment: Congratulations, this structure breaks ChemDraw's structure-to-name feature too! I'll try LexiChem when I'm at work tomorrow.

Comment: I can't even search chemspider with the skeleton (non-aromatic rings) with similarity search (tanimoto 99%) - I get an error. This is the devil's own structure...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't resist : sigma-aldritch site also fails, as does pubchem. only e-molecules seems to allow searches by drawing it! https://orderbb.emolecules.com/search/#?smiles=Cc1ccc(cc1)c1cccc(c1c1ccc(cc1)c1c(cccc1c1ccc(cc1)c1ccccc1)c1ccc(cc1)c1ccccc1)c1ccc(cc1)C&searchtype=si&similimit=0.8&system-type=BB&p=1

Comment: The preferred systematic name in phane nomenclature for the outer ring (without the “1,4-phenylene” bridge) is “1,3,5,7(1,2),2,4,6,8(1,4)-octabenzenacyclooctaphane”. By way of comparison, the similar [8]cycloparaphenylene with the systematic name “1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8(1,4)-octabenzenacyclooctaphane” is described in http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c2sc20719b.

Comment: I get undecacyclo[?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?]tetrapentaconta-1,3(9),4(10),5(13),6(12),7(45),8(46),11(49),14(52),15(35),16(24),17(36),18(26),19(37),20(28),21(38),22(30),23(39),25(40),27(41),29(42),31(43),32(34),33(44),47,50(54),51(53)-heptacosaene from LexiChem. The "?" (actually BLAH) comes when LexiChem aborts numbering a complicated ring system.

Comment: I actually suggest issuing this as a Twitter challenge to ChemDraw, OpenEye, ChemDoodle, ACD, etc.

Comment: Even though this compound has no chiral center, the stereochemistry would be very interesting.

Comment: Related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73103/does-iupac-nomenclature-have-the-ability-to-name-all-organic-compounds

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It indeed can be named quite nicely using the recent "phane" nomenclature from the [Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069), here is the example<sup>*</sup>

> [image: sample schema with structures and names]

By abstracting to the bicyclo phane composed of nine benzene nodes ("superatoms") of three kinds, we get

[image: schema with structures]

**1,5(1,3,2),2,4,6,8,9(1,4),3,7(1,2)-nonabenzenabicyclo[3.3.1]nonaphane**

Note that the "superatom" (more precise "amplificant") locant ordering matters. If the numbers in the first parentheses were sorted, it would mean a different structure, that is little bit hard to draw in 2D:

[image: srtucture for the obsolete answer]

1,5(1,2,3),2,4,6,8,9(1,4),3,7(1,2)-nonabenzenabicyclo[3.3.1]nonaphane

Publicly accessible references:

- [Phane Nomenclature, Part I: Phane Parent Names](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/phane/)
- [Phane Nomenclature, Part II: Modification of the Degree of Hydrogenation and Substitution Derivatives of Phane Parent Hydrides](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/phane2/)

---

*) Please note there is a mistake in the example from the book, the pyridine (**4**) has wrong internal ring numbering - 4 should be replaced with 5. The name is correct, though. (It is mentioned in [errata](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/bibliog/BBerrors.html), for page 310).

Comment: "[3.3.1] " What does it stand for?

Comment: @Mockingbird, "[3.3.1]" describes that the skeleton composed of two cycles (*bi*cyclo) has three branches (that each begin and end in two distinct nodes - it is always the case; here they are X) (therefore three dot-separated numbers) that have **3**, **3** (two identical (X)YZY(X) branches) and **1** ((X)Y(X) branch) nodes ("superatoms") respectively, excluding the X end points, total 9 (*nona*phane). This type of naming is also used for hydrocarbons, etc. If X, Y and Z were just carbon atom (with hydrogens), it would be bicyclo[3.3.1]nonane.

Comment: @mykkhal what if there are substituents? Like Cl or Br joined to one molecule.

Comment: @Mockingbird, numbering is done by indicating the number of the "superatom" and the position on it as upper index, so this structure with chlorine on all peripheral positions would be 1⁴,1⁵,1⁶,2²,2³,3³,3⁴,3⁵,3⁶,4²,4³,5⁴,5⁵,5⁶,6²,6³,7³,7⁴,7⁵,7⁶,‌​8²,8³-docosachloro-1‌​,5(1,3,2),2,4,6,8,9(‌​1,4),3,7(1,2)-nonabe‌​nzenabicyclo[3.3.1]n‌​onaphane

Comment: "Note that the "superatom" (more precise "amplificant") locant ordering matters. If the numbers in the first parentheses were sorted, it would mean a different structure, that is little bit hard to draw in 2D" Does it only matter for the superatoms by which the "[3.3.1]" is specified?

Comment: @Mockingbird, I am not sure I understand your recent question, the bicyclo skeleton name completely defines node ("superatom"), but does not define any "amplificant". Sorry that I could be more explanatory, so I attached reference links.

Comment: I mean the sequence in the first parantheses of your example mattered only because those two benzene molecules are the start and endpoint of the 2 cycles.

Comment: @Mockingbird, this is not the exact reason, but is related. It matters, because of symmetry or asymmetry. It matters, because the branches are different. It can be vaguely said that it matters because the three numbers in the square brackets are different. If the superatom amplificant would be e.g. pyridine, the order would matter also for those in-branch nodes (with only two locants in the parentheses), if they were bonded asymmetrically, which is not possible for benzenediyl, in this sense.

Comment: I don't understand the order in the first parenthese is in basis of what?

Comment: @Mockingbird, .. the order is based on several rules - lowest set of locants, bute more importantly, it is also based on the order of the number of superatom nodes in the parent skeleton, boned to the amplificant locations. Please read through the refs,  and draw possible structures yourself, it is no room here for the deep explanation. See rule **PhI-2.3.2.2**

Answer (score 18):

ChemDoodle 8 can name this via the extended von Baeyer system, although the name is quite long. Thanks for putting up this nice example though!

[image: von Baeyer name]

Undecacyclo[18.18.6.2<sup>2,5</sup>.2<sup>12,15</sup>.2<sup>21,24</sup>.2<sup>31,34</sup>.2<sup>40,43</sup>.0<sup>6,11</sup>.0<sup>16,44</sup>.0<sup>25,30</sup>.0<sup>35,39</sup>]tetrapentaconta-1(39),2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16(44),17,19,21,23,25(30),26,28,31,33,35,37,40,42,45,47,49,51,53-heptacosaene

Comment: Although impressive, the name ignores the identity of benzenes and treats the compound as poly-alekene.

Comment: Interesting, Marvin Sketch seems to agree with ChemDoodle and Chem Office can not generate a name at all.