# What is the longest systematic name used for a compound that actually exists?

Tags: nomenclature, synthesis

The answer to this question ([Does IUPAC nomenclature have the ability to name all organic compounds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73103/does-iupac-nomenclature-have-the-ability-to-name-all-organic-compounds)) which references the complex biomolecule [Maitotoxin](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maitotoxin) which has a ridiculously long systematic name.

I doubt that this is the longest systematic name ever used for a synthesised and fully characterised compound. What is?

PS I'm sure we can name many proteins using stupidly long names, but I suspect that is cheating. Let's stick to lab-made compounds and the published literature.

Comment: This question can never have a confident single answer, I'm afraid. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @hBy2Py On the contrary, it can have a confident answer if we restrict it to names used in the literature. That answer might change over time, but, in principle, we can always have a single answer.

Comment: In principle, yes, there is always only one winner in this race. But in practice, we never will have a single answer due to the epistemological problem: the 'world record name' as tracked here will just keep getting longer as people on the site happen to discover new chemicals with longer names, or as people who know of long names happen to come across this question. I stand by my vote.

Comment: @matt_black Used in literature is not a really good criterion. Since several software is capable to generate names, it is by chance if someone put a full name somewhere in his paper or supplementary information, while mostly calling it compound 3 in the manuscript.

Comment: @hBy2Py Flagging and Voting are meant to be anonymous. I strongly advise you to keep it that way.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Welcome to Chem.SE. They are anonymous if the voter/flagger wishes them to be. Revealing one's votes and/or flags cast is entirely acceptable and common.

Comment: @PrittBalgopal If anything, I would much prefer if people told me why they downvoted/flagged my post rather than just receiving a bunch of downvotes. I believe the site actually suggests that you explain in the comments why are downvoting something and how it can potentially be improved.