# What is the IUPAC name of fullerene like molecules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I wonder what the IUPAC names of fullerene-like molecules, I mean all those hydrocarbons with 3-D structure. Do we have another name of these compounds or are they classified as aromatic?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. Please see our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/).

Comment: From [Does IUPAC nomenclature have the ability to name all organic compounds? (Chemistry.se)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/73106/4945) we find *Pure & Appl. Chem.* **1997,** *69* (7), pp. 1411-1434 [pdf mirrored on iupac.org](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1997/pdf/6907x1411.pdf). And obviously the blue book 2013: http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069

Comment: It seems that you are asking two different Qs. It is possible to name each fullerene.. The synthesis guys do it so I have no refs at hand. Is better to consider them as a class, as for aromaticity is present or no depending on which aspect is accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found relevent sources here:

https://old.iupac.org/publications/pac/1997/pdf/6907x1411.pdf
http://www.sbcs.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/fullerene/

However, I still wonder if we have another name for all those hydrocarbons with 3-dimensional structures. Should they be regarded as a subclass of "aromatic" or do we have another name for them?

Comment: This is not really an answer and in my opinion should be edited in your question.

Comment: I am considering converting that to an edit. Right now it poses more questions than it answers. In addition, whilst the links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for reference.

Comment: Polycyclic cage? http://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=CHEBI%3A33640 - Agreed that this question could do with a cleanup